# Remove duplicates of a Data.Sequence

Tags: haskell, containers, unique

I have a sequence `Seq a` with `Eq a` and I want to remove the duplicates inside this sequence. I do

```hs
fromList $ nub $ toList mysequence
```

Is there a more efficient way?

This is a sequence of `Edge` where

```hs
data Edge = Edge Int Int
  deriving (Show, Read)
instance Eq Edge where
    (==) :: Edge -> Edge -> Bool
    Edge i j == Edge i' j' = (i == i' && j == j') || (i == j' && j == i')
```

Comment: If `Hashable` is allowed `hashNub` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.4.2/docs/Data-Witherable.html#v:hashNub

Comment: `nub` itself is not very efficient, since it requires quadratic time, so even if there is an algorithm specifically made for `Seq`s or through a typeclass, that can optimize it a bit, but still in terms of time complexity, it will scale quadratic. So if `Hashable` is allowed, that boosts the algorithm *a lot*.

Comment: Removing duplicates efficiently requires hashes or at least `Ord` (sort the sequence first, then discard adjacent equal elements). With only `Eq` I don't think there's anything better than the inefficient quadratic-time `nub`.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I completed my question. Roughly, this is a sequence of unordered pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [**`Hashable`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable/docs/Data-Hashable.html#t:Hashable) is allowed to include as type constraint, you can use [**`hashNub :: (Witherable t, Eq a, Hashable a) => t a -> t a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.4.2/docs/Data-Witherable.html#v:hashNub) , which will use the hashes to boost uniqness checks.

If only `Eq` is allowed, there is not much we can do but perform *quadratic matching*. While perhaps it is possible to do this a bit more efficient than converting it to and from a list in between, it will likely not matter much: the conversions from and to a list are *linear*, whereas `nub` runs in quadratic time, so most of the time will be wasted checking of two elements match.

In this case, we can implement a hash function that hashes first the smallest of the two numbers and then the largest, so:

```
instance Hashable Edge where
  hashWithSalt s (Edge m1 m2) = hashWithSalt s (min m1 m2) `hashWithSalt` (max m1 m2)
```